# how to generate the "realese/res" and "debug/res" automatically in android studio?

Tags: android, google-maps

I am creating a mobile application that contains a map interface using android studio. To fix the problem of visibilty of the google map on the application, I must change the google API on the XML files in the two folders **"release / res / ..... xml"** and **"debug / res / ..... xml"**

But in my project, I can not find these two folders even if I already generate a signed application
What should I do ?

[image: ScreenShot]

Answer (score 1):

You are using the **Project view**.
Expand the `src` dir and you will find the `res` folder is under:

```
app/src/main/res
app/src/debug/res/
app/src/release/res/
```